# How to set my main menu items

Tags: menus

I am new to WordPress development, hope this is not a too stupid question. How can I setup my Menu such that it has links to

- Home
- About (Page)
- Blog (I think posts in all categories except Portfolio & In the Works)
- Portfolio (Category)
- In the Works (Category)

I think all is easy except I dont immediately see a way to point to the home page (maybe I need to "hardcode" something like `http://domain.com`?)

Also how can I have a link to the Blog

Just in case, I am refering to the below screen

[image]

Comment: There are no "stupid" questions. As long as you feel and think your question is within the scope of what has been outlined in the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq), feel free to post them here. We try to help as much as we can. I know that I don't speak for myself alone.

Answer (score 1):

For Home, you can use a custom links, the second box in the left column, referring to your screenshoot.

For the blog, you must have a page where there are all the categories except "portfolio" and "in the works". The link it using custom links

Answer (score 0):

jiewmeng - The page that you created as your home page should be identified as the home page under the **Dashboard-->Settings-->Reading**.  Your blog page should be identified there as well under "Posts Page".

Now create the menu.  Your screen shot only shows an "About" page.  If you had/have created additional pages, select them and click the add to menu button.

Similarly, any categories you wish to add to the menu can be selected and then added to the menu.